# Duplication of vertices in Amazon Neptune

Tags: duplicates, gremlin, amazon-neptune, graph-neural-network

I want to create some logic that does the following in Amazon Neptune using Gremlin:

**1.** Load a row of data that contains **customer_id** and **postcode** columns

**2.** Check if the **postcode** value from that row already exists in the database:

**A.** If it does, then create a new vertex for the row's **customer_id** value and then create a new edge that makes a connection *from* the **customer_id** vertex that has just been created *to* the pre-existing **postcode** vertex

**B.** Else, if it does not, then create a new vertex for the row's **customer_id** value, create a new vertex for the row's **postcode** value and then create a new edge that makes a connection *from* the **customer_id** vertex that has just been created *to* the **postcode** vertex that has just been created

- The purpose of this is to avoid creating duplicate vertices.
- I am open to different approaches if you can see flaws in my logic.
- I have tried a few methods but I've been unable to get a single piece of logic to perform all of the above.
- I am using Gremlin.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to ensure uniqueness, each vertex and edge in a graph in Neptune must have a unique ID.  So it is good practice to leverage that concept to the fullest.  Deterministic IDs are also great for fast lookups, as a lookup by a vertex/edge ID is the fastest operation in Neptune.  If you don't supply a value for the vertex/edge IDs, then Neptune creates an ID using a UUID.

After that you'll want to consider using a conditional write pattern. In Gremlin, you can follow the pattern documented in Practical Gremlin [1].

So the pattern, for your use case, would follow something like:

```
g.V().hasLabel('customer').has('customer_id',<id>).
    fold().coalesce(
        unfold(),
        addV('customer').property('customer_id',<id>)
    ).aggregate('c').
    V().hasLabel('postcode').has('postcode',<postcode>).
        fold().coalesce(
            unfold(),
            addV('postcode').property('postcode',<postcode>)
        ).
    addE('hasPostCode').from(select('c').unfold())
```

> Note: The `aggregate()` step is used above because we're wanting to label something in our query but then we need to cross a collapsing barrier step (`fold()`) later on in the query.  If we were to use `as()`, the label will not persist beyond the collapsing barrier step.

If using deterministic IDs, this could be simplified.  Say we use an ID nomenclature of "customer-id" for customer vertices and "postcode-code" for postcode vertices:

```
g.V(<customer_id>).
    fold().coalesce(
        unfold(),
        addV('customer').property(id,<customer_id>)
    ).
    V(<postcode_id>).
        fold().coalesce(
            unfold(),
            addV('postcode').property(id,<postcode_id>)
        ).
    addE('hasPostCode').from(V(<customer_id>)
```

[1] https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html#upsert

Comment: what exactly do you mean by ID? I thought an edge/vertex only has three features: (1) label, (2) property and (3) property value?

Comment: your code is very helpful, but I am not concerned with checking for vertices that have label **customer** - I am only concerned with checking for vertices that have

Comment: Each vertex and edge has at minimum, a unique ID and a label.  If you do not specify an ID, then Neptune creates an ID using a UUID.  And it is fine if you don't need to check for a label first. Neptune doesn't have any way to define schema, so there's the possibility for having the same property name on different labeled vertices.  It is just more common practice to check for a vertex of a given label then evaluate a property.  But the label check is optional.

Comment: For the ID, you define a custom ID using `property(id,<value>)` and note that is `id` and not `'id'`.  The latter would create a property called "id".